# How to measure ratio of Na to K in table salt?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment

Some people state, that the salt which we buy at the supermarket contains too much potassium chloride. For me it seems to be a hoax, but I want to have a proof.

Is there any way to measure the percentage of sodium chloride and potassium chloride in salt at home without special equipment?

If it is not possible, what kind of equipment is needed?

Comment: It doesn't make much difference, but it's [potassium iodide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_iodide), which is added. Iodide anion concentration would be *much* easier to find out.

Comment: RE: "Some people state..." -- Love it. Reference to vague and unknown authority.

Comment: Atomic absorption spectroscopy, if you can get the use of an instrument.

Comment: It would be very very easy to do with XRF. You'd just need to press the salt into a pellet in a die.

Comment: @Mithoron It could be _iodate_, not iodide.

Comment: @MaxW who states it, does not really matter. The question can be understood and probably answered :)

Comment: @GáborLipták - I think you miss the point that I was trying to make. By using "Some people" as the authority it is impossible to backtrack who actually said what. So such a claim could be on the Skeptics forum asking if any recognizable authority has actually stated that "regular salt" has too much potassium.

Comment: Two problems: 1) why worry about the amount of potassium? I isn't harmful. 2) Why not just take what the label says: most authorities insist on ingredient labelling and this should help identify any salt with more than traces of potassium (some high potassium salt is sold as a "low sodium" alternative to normal salt).

Comment: Flame spectroscopy could be used to quantitate Na:K ratio.

Comment: @ELawrence Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. I have converted you answer to a comment and deleted your other answer, which was also a comment. Please only user the answer field for actual answers. On our site we are looking for more detailed and referenced answers, rather stan one-line statements.

Comment: @MaxW The question is not asking about an authoritative source, though. The question is asking how to perform an experiment. It would be just as valid of an experiment if you dreamed it, or if you took drugs and a fence told you.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: no, you cannot do it at home. Some analytical techniques are mentioned in the comments.

However I decided to post because LIKELY people should not worry about the Potassium content of table salt.

Table salt (normally "just" NaCl) containing as much of 28.5 % of Potassium (might be more perhaps, but this is what I have at hand) can be sold free of medical prescription not only in drugstores/pharmacies but also in supermarkets, where it can be found in the special diets section or alongside standard salt. 
It is a dietary salt indicated to limit the Sodium intake (for instance in case of high blood pressure). 
Its price is much higher that that of common salt. It can be used to replace salt in all kitchen uses. It is less salty and more bitter than the normal salt, and one has to "get the mouth" to it.

I would therefore infer that is highly unlikely that something sold as table salt NaCl could contain so much potassium to worry about. Especially when some of those worrying of it, might be prone to buy Potassium integrators during summer :)

Disclaimer: it is clear that the potassium content of whatever table salt sold in food stores and supermarkets should not be matter of concerns however, as for any diets and integrators (Fe, K, Mg...) there exists health conditions which are incompatible. Before starting a diet or taking dietetic salts one should seek the advice of his/her physician. [image: ingredients and content of a hyposodic table salt]